# Why is my JSF 2.0 custom component rendered several times when using ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, custom-component

I have created a custom jsf 2.0 component for a special userinput widget.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value"></cc:attribute>
    <cc:attribute name="editmode" default="true" type="java.lang.Boolean"></cc:attribute>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
 ....
</cc:implementation>
```

The component contains some standard input components and makes use of jsf 2.0 ajax behavior. 
Everything in my component works fine, and I use it multiple times in my application.

Now I run into a strange problem when I am using the component with a f:ajax region.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:marty="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/marty"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <!-- Ajax region -->
    <f:ajax>
        <h:panelGroup id="timesheet_panel" binding="#{timesheetListComponent}">

        .....
    <!-- my custom component ->
        <marty:userInput value="#{workitem.item['nammanager']}" editmode="true" />
        ....
       <h:commandButton value="#{message.search}"
            action="/pages/workitems/workitem"
            actionListener="#{timesheetController.reset}">
            <f:ajax render="timesheet_panel" onevent="updateTimesheetPanel" />
       </h:commandButton>
     ....
     </f:ajax>
</ui:composition>
```

The stange thing now is that when the command button was clicked and the ajax request was fired my custom component appears 3 times in my form.

Can anybody explain Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the strange behavior. It was a JavaScript problem.
My component contains jquery scripts to hide some parts of the component. After the ajax call was completed the jquery scripts was not triggered so the layout of the component was corrupted. So it was a javaScript problem and not a problem with my jsf component as I thought first. Sorry for the wrong question.